# Nexus Repository with TLS: conda not working

Tags: https, conda, nexus3

I've installed Nexus repository on a internal server (Windows) and got it working as expected from my laptop (Windows). I then enabled TLS/https according to [this guide](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/system-configuration/configuring-ssl) from sonatype themselves using a self-signed cert. I can connect to the repository manager with https and it works fine.

The certificate was created following [this guide](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465768-SSL-Certificate-Guide) also from sonatype. From that I go my nexus.pem file. According to the [conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/non-standard-certs.html) I added that file to environment variable REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE.

I then adjusted my conda and pip config to connect to nexus using https. However even though https works in the browser, when trying to install anything with conda I get a HTTPError:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://myserver.com:8443/repository/anaconda-proxy/main/win-64/repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://myserver.com:8443/repository/anaconda-proxy/main/win-64'
```

I can copy&paste the link in the error into my browser and it works just fine. Therefore only explanation I have is that it's some issue with the ssl cert but the error doesn't show what the issue could be.

How can I get a more meaningful error? Or how can I resolve the issue?

EDIT:

Indeed it's an issue with the certificate. If I remove REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE and set

```
conda config --set ssl_verify False
```

Then it works. But that's not really what I want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can search and try to solve problems for hours and some minutes after posting here I find the solution. Happens way too often, argh.

Simply put the error was my own fault. The self-signed cert was issues to `example.mycompany.com` but in the `.condarc`file I had put in links to channel using just the alias eg `https://example/repository/anaconda-proxy/main/` instead of the full host name eg `https://example.mycompany.com/repository/anaconda-proxy/main/`